# how to execute multiple AsyncTask in one class

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I'm using Android SDK 4.0 API14 and I want to run multiple AsyncTask in one class, I want the called async task to wait while the one before it is finished, but is seems I can't accomplish this, even if I test the status of the one currently being executed. this is my code :

```
if(isNetworkAvailable()){
        new SpinnerTask().execute();
        new RiderTask().execute();
        new BankTask().execute();
        }

    //spinner bank
        public class BankTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{
            String url="http://128.21.30.37:8080/E-Policy/ios/spaj_bank.htm?type=pusat";
            public BankTask(){
            this.url=url;
            System.out.println(url);}
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            dialog=new ProgressDialog(Menu_SPPAJ.this);
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Menu_SPPAJ.this, "Mohon Menunggu", "Penarikan data Rider..");}
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    String result = "";
                    try {
                        result = Connection.get(url);
                        System.out.println("tes " + result);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO: handle exception
                        result = "";    
                        }
                        return result;
                        }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
//          Response(result.replace("\n", "").trim());
            System.out.println("done for Bank");
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);

                JSONArray PRODUK = jsonObject.getJSONArray("BANK PUSAT");

                for (int i=0; i<PRODUK.length();i++){

                    JSONObject spinner = PRODUK.getJSONObject(i);
                            String LSBP_NAMA = spinner.optString("LSBP_NAMA");
                            int LSBP_ID = spinner.optInt("LSBP_ID");
                        helper.InsertBank(LSBP_ID, LSBP_NAMA);
//                      ListSpinner.add(VarSpinner);
                        System.out.println("tes VarSpinner");
                    }
                }catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("TES", e.getMessage());
            }
            }
            }  
//spinner bank
            public class CabBankTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{
            String url="http://128.21.30.37:8080/E-Policy/ios/spaj_bank.htm?type=cabang";
                public CabBankTask(){
                this.url=url;
                System.out.println(url);}
                @Override
                    protected void onPreExecute() {
                    super.onPreExecute();
                    dialog=new ProgressDialog(Menu_SPPAJ.this);
                    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Menu_SPPAJ.this, "Mohon Menunggu", "Penarikan data Rider..");}
                    @Override
                    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            String result = "";
                            try {
                                result = Connection.get(url);
                                System.out.println("tes " + result);
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                // TODO: handle exception
                                result = "";    
                                }
                                return result;
                                }
                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    super.onPostExecute(result);
//                  Response(result.replace("\n", "").trim());
                    System.out.println("done for Cabang");
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);

                        JSONArray PRODUK = jsonObject.getJSONArray("BANK CABANG");

                        for (int i=0; i<PRODUK.length();i++){

                            JSONObject spinner = PRODUK.getJSONObject(i);
                                    int LSBP_ID = spinner.optInt("LSBP_ID");
                                    int LBN_ID = spinner.optInt("LBN_ID");
                                    String LBN_NAMA = spinner.optString("LBN_NAMA");
                                helper.InsertCabBank(LSBP_ID, LBN_ID, LBN_NAMA);
//                              ListSpinner.add(VarSpinner);
                                System.out.println("tes VarSpinner");
                            }
                        }catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.d("TES", e.getMessage());
                    }
                    }
                    }

    //spinner produk    
        public class SpinnerTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{
//          String url="http://epolicy.sinarmasmsiglife.co.id/ios/spaj_prod.htm?model=1";
            String url="http://128.21.30.37:8080/E-Policy/ios/spaj_prod.htm?type=bancass";
                    public SpinnerTask(){
                        this.url=url;
                        System.out.println(url);
                    }
                    @Override
                    protected void onPreExecute() {
                        super.onPreExecute();
                        dialog=new ProgressDialog(Menu_SPPAJ.this);
//                      dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Menu_SPPAJ.this, "Mohon Menunggu", "Penarikan data Produk..");
                    }
                    @Override
                    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    String result = "";
                                    try {
                                        result = Connection.get(url);
                                        System.out.println("tes " + result);
                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        // TODO: handle exception
                                        result = "";    
                                    }
                                    return result;
                                }
                                @Override
                                protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//                                  dialog.dismiss();
                                    super.onPostExecute(result);
                                    fetchResponse(result.replace("\n", "").trim());
                                    System.out.println("done for product");
                                }
                                }

                private void fetchResponse(String result) {
                    if (!result.equals("")) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);

                            JSONArray PRODUK = jsonObject.getJSONArray("PRODUK");

                            for (int i=0; i<PRODUK.length();i++){

                                JSONObject spinner = PRODUK.getJSONObject(i);
                                        String LSBS_ID = spinner.optString("LSBS_ID");
                                        String LSBS_NAME = spinner.optString("LSBS_NAME");
                                    helper.InsertSpin_Produk(LSBS_ID, LSBS_NAME);
//                                  ListSpinner.add(VarSpinner);
                                    System.out.println("tes VarSpinner");

                                    JSONArray PRODUK1 = spinner.getJSONArray("SUB_PRODUK");
                                    for (int j=0; j<PRODUK1.length();j++){
                                        JSONObject sub = PRODUK1.getJSONObject(j);
                                        String LSDBS_NUMBER = sub.optString("LSDBS_NUMBER");
                                        String LSDBS_NAME = sub.optString("LSDBS_NAME");
                                        helper.InsertSpin_SubProduk(LSBS_ID,LSBS_NAME,LSDBS_NUMBER, LSDBS_NAME);

                                        System.out.println("tes VarSpinner 1\2");
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.d("TES", e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                }    
//Rider
    public class RiderTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{
            String url="http://128.21.30.37:8080/E-Policy/ios/spaj_prod.htm?type=rider";
                    public RiderTask(){
                        this.url=url;
                        System.out.println(url);
                    }
                    @Override
                    protected void onPreExecute() {
                        super.onPreExecute();
                        dialog=new ProgressDialog(Menu_SPPAJ.this);
                        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Menu_SPPAJ.this, "Mohon Menunggu", "Penarikan data Rider..");
                    }
                    @Override
                    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    String result = "";
                                    try {
                                        result = Connection.get(url);
                                        System.out.println("tes " + result);
                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        // TODO: handle exception
                                        result = "";    
                                    }
                                    return result;
                                }
                                @Override
                                protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    super.onPostExecute(result);
                                    Response(result.replace("\n", "").trim());
                                    System.out.println("done for ridern");
                                }
                                }
```

is there any way to run multiple Asynctask in one class? thank u very much

Comment: yes it is. `onPostExecute` of first launch second and so on...

Comment: Refer [this](https://github.com/vitkhudenko/test_asynctask) may help you

Answer (score 2):

Have a look on the [AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#executeOnExecutor%28java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20Params...%29) method. It will run AsyncTasks in parallel. But make sure that the Tasks you run are independent from each other. As mentioned in the docs there is no given order in which the Tasks will be executed.

Call your Tasks like this:

```
new SpinnerTask().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
```

Answer (score -1):

What you can do is, you can call second `AsyncTask` on `onPostExecute()` of first `AsyncTask` and so on.

e.g

```
public class FirstAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                         // your code

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            // new SecondAsyncTask().execute();
    }}
```